# React: Render function being called for component that isn't on my page after setState()

Tags: reactjs

I have a single file with a number of common related components that I have included in all of my pages. Within that file is a component class called `Tabs` which only has a render function and a number of props it's supposed to be given.

On my pages which don't ever use this component, I am getting an error related to props not being set for that component in it's render function. This is occurring at some point after I call `setState()` on a different component. The error and React trace according to dev-tools is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The above error occurred in the <Tabs> component:

    at Tabs (<anonymous>:331:9)
    at EventList (<anonymous>:147:9)
    at div
    at EventListPage (<anonymous>:23:9)
```

For context, `EventListPage` has a `EventList`, and *neither* of them (nor any component on the page) have a `Tabs`. On other similar pages I have, I get basically the same error but in the components for those pages instead of `EventList` stuff. Also, the `setState()` call I mentioned before is in the `EventListPage` class if that's relevant.

I can't for the life of me figure out how or why that component's render function could ever be called since the component itself isn't ever referenced/instantiated anywhere on these pages and especially not within the components that the error trace is saying it came from before it ended up at the Tabs class.

I know React keeps some sort of internal list for components that need to be updated after a `setState()`, is it possible that this unused component is somehow getting into this list? What can I do to try to fix this or to try to find the root of the problem?

Tabs:

```
class Tabs extends React.Component{
    static idInc = 1;

    render(){
        let headers = [];
        let bodies = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.props.headerLabels.length; i++){
            const h = this.props.headerLabels[i];
            const b = this.props.bodies[i];
            const id = (this.props.customId ? this.props.customId : 'tabs' + ++Tabs.idInc) + '-' + i;
            const active = (this.props.activeTab == i || this.props.activeTab == h) ? ' active' : '';
            headers.push(
                <li key={h} className="nav-item">
                    <a className={'nav-link' + active} href={'#' + id} data-toggle="tab">{h}</a>
                </li>
            );
            bodies.push(
                <div key={id} id={id} className={'tab-pane' + active}>{b}</div>
            );
        }
        return(
            <div>
                <ol className="nav nav-tabs">{headers}</ol>
                <div className="tab-content">{bodies}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Also to add: Commenting out the entire `Tabs` class does cause the problem to stop occuring, although this isn't a viable solution since I need that class for other things.

Comment: you can edit your own question if you have additional information.

Comment: I'm also not sure how we can help you with no code provided..

Comment: I'm not sure what code to even share. I never call that class from any of my code. You want the EventsList class? Its pretty small, does'nt have anything helpful in it. I'm just looking for advice on what to look for in this situation

Comment: Can you share the code of `Tabs` at least?

Comment: Sure. Other than some of the funniness of how I actually chose to make it there isn't anything fundamentally wrong with it (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Having gone pretty deep down the devtools rabit hole, I found that in my 'common' file I was somehow overwriting the 'Table' name with the Tabs class so when I imported Table in my page it was trying to render a Tabs. Silly mistake, hard to trace down despite its simplicity.